# Spring layers Repository and Service, BestPractices

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, architecture, repository-pattern

what are the best practices of using repository layers into service layers?

```
Repository1 -> Service1 - \
                             > Service3
Repository2 -> Service2 - /
```

OR

```
Repository1 -\ 
               > Service1 
Repository2 -/
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer your first solution. One repository -> One Service.

S from **SOLID** mnemonic is Single responsibility principle.

If you inject two repos to one service it will not be one responsibility per class.

Answer (score 1):

I think solution 2 is good.

A service can do a transaction which need 2-3 repositories. 
A service is more like an transaction from user's perspective.

That is my thought.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your code style:
you can code by components or by logical flow. As you can see from the answers it is totally debatable. A more modular approach would be to totally separate the implementation by a certain characteristic. But more in general: do you have to code in a team or is it a "single player project"? if it is your project just do as you think it's better (component, logical flow), but if you are in a team you have to be modular. Many programmers prefer to concentrate their code without using the dao layer (or even the service), so the code is lighter, but obviosuly it can be a mess! As a personal choice I prefer the second example.